# Finding replacement upvc door keeps

Tags: doors, lock, latches

We've recently moved into a new house and we've found that some of the doors are not closing properly. We had a locksmith in to change the locks and he mentioned that we needed to get a 'keep' for each door with the problem but I'm having trouble sourcing the replacements.

There are a couple of doors that don't need replacing and the keep in them looks like this:

[image]

Some candidates that I've found online are here:

- [Avocet Replacement Centre Latch Keep](https://www.upvc-store.co.uk/products/avocet-replacement-centre-latch-keep-striker-plate-for-upvc-door-lock-keep) (58 mm)
- [Lockmaster Mila Master Upvc Door Centre Latch Keep Strike Plate](https://www.upvc-store.co.uk/products/lockmaster-mila-master-upvc-door-centre-latch-keep-strike-plate) (52 mm)

When I measure the screw centres on a working door, it looks to be 56 mm as shown here:

[image]

So I guess my questions are:

- Am I measuring the screw centres correctly?
- Does anyone know where I can source the above keep?
- Is there some tolerance around the screw centres where it could work with a distance slightly more or less?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're measuring the screw distances correctly, centerline of screw to centerline of screw. If you can't find exactly what you want online, try hitting a few locksmith shops.

There is some tolerance in mounting these. Depending on the type, you can drill new holes or with a small round file, turn the existing holes into slotted holes. I have seen some that had no holes and you just drilled where you needed them to be.